# MySQL Multi JOIN extremely slow

Tags: mysql, database, performance

This is a problem that I'm not sure exactly where the root cause could be, so I'm going to provide details and the trouble points I've thought of. Any help would be awesome (beer on me if you live nearby). I have these three tables:

**practices:**

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`deleted` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_update_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
```

**locations:**

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`practice_fk` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`phone` char(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`fax` char(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
`address_two` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`state` char(2) NOT NULL,
`zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`lat` decimal(7,5) DEFAULT NULL,
`lng` decimal(7,5) DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_update_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`practice_name_temp` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

**contacts:**

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`location_fk` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`practice_fk` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`fname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
`mobile` char(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`deleted` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_update_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The basic idea behind the architecture is there is a list of practices. A practice can have multiple locations, but a location cannot exist without being associated with a practice. Then, a practice can also have multiple contacts, but a contact must be associated with a practice and a location. [This is where one part of the problem may begin]. So, I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS practice_id, 
                p.name, 
                l.id AS location_id, 
                address AS location_address, 
                l.phone AS disp_phone, 
                CONCAT(pc.fname, ' ', pc.lname) AS practiceContact, 
                CONCAT(lc.fname, ' ', lc.lname) AS locationContact,
                pcc.qty AS practice_only_contact_qty,
                lcc.qty AS location_contact_qty,
                (pcc.qty + lcc.qty) AS contactQty
            FROM practices p
            LEFT JOIN practice_locations l on l.practice_fk=p.id
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT count(id) AS qty, practice_fk 
                FROM practice_contacts 
                GROUP BY practice_fk
            ) pcc ON pcc.practice_fk=p.id
            LEFT JOIN practice_contacts pc ON pc.practice_fk=pcc.practice_fk AND pcc.qty=1
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT count(id) AS qty, location_fk 
                FROM practice_contacts 
                GROUP BY location_fk
            ) lcc ON lcc.location_fk=l.id
            LEFT JOIN practice_contacts lc ON lc.location_fk=lcc.location_fk AND lcc.qty=1
            WHERE p.name IS NOT NULL AND p.deleted IS NULL
            GROUP BY p.id
            ORDER BY p.name ASC, l.state, l.city, l.address;
```

What this query is supposed to do is:

- Gather the practice ID and name.
- If there is a single location, grab it's address. Otherwise, grab the first location's address
- If there is a single contact associated with the practice, grab their name. Otherwise, grab the first contact's name
- Count how many contacts there are associated with the practice
- Count how many locations are associated with the practice
- Group all this together by the practice ID, then order it alphabetically according to the practice name, then by location

So, it does all of that right now. REALLLLLLLYYY SLOWLY. When I only had five records in the practices table, and less than 20 in the other two tables, the query worked great. Now I've imported data into these tables (~9,000 records in practices, 14,000+ in locations, and 25,000+ in contacts), and this query takes over 28 seconds to return what I need. If I pull the group by's out, we're looking at 33+ seconds. Screw me, right?!

Obviously, this is unacceptable. This dataset is relatively small, and this application is only going to grow with potentially millions of contacts being in here at some point. So, I'm wondering if this is in fact a three plus part issue:

- **First part:** should I introduce a reference table [kind of like a view], to store these relationships -- something like:

  ```
  `id` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `practice_fk` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `location_fk` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `contact_fk` int(11) unsigned not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  KEY(practice_fk),
  KEY(location_fk),
  KEY(contact_fk)
  ```

  But if I do that, I'm unsure of how I would construct the query to pull the data as I need? And would it offer any performance benefits.
- **Second Part:** I don't have the proper indexes in place. After scouring the MySQL docs and stumbling across this post (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/why-are-simple-selects-on-innodb-100x-slower-than-on-myisam) I've come to understand InnoDB is a slow pig. This is unacceptable from a UX perspective but from an architecture perspective, I'm locked into this engine. How would I set up the indexes properly to get this query back to the sub-second range?
- **Third part:** my query is garbage. I think this is probably the biggest culprit. I'm still learning how to structure these more complex SQL queries, and this is took some effort to craft in itself, so any pointers on how to make this thing less of a pig would be great.

I've tried a variety of manipulations on my query (pulling out group by's, dropping the order by, etc) and there's hardly any change. The query consistently is running at between 28 and 33 seconds. Any guidance will be beyond appreciated.

Comment: Did you create foreign key between your practice, location and contact tables?

Comment: Essentially, all the fields involved in join should be indexed

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also since this is about SQL performance/optimization, what have you read about that? See [ask].

Comment: "Grab the first ..." -- Would you allow "grab any ..."?  This _may_ speed things up.  If "first" is important, define "first" - by time?  by alphabet?  by id?

Comment: "InnoDB is a slow pig" -- **WRONG**.  About the only case is `COUNT(*)` of the entire table.  In _most_ other cases, with current versions, InnoDB is competitive with MyISAM.

Comment: lamandy, yes there are foreign key references.

philipxy, thank you for the utterly helpful comment. I figured the details in this question were adequate, especially given the answers. I only post on SO if absolutely needed unlike most people you probably respond to with this response.

Rick, Thanks for your answer/comments! You're a life saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of these can be 'fixed', but they jump out at me as performance red-flags:

- Don't mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  They sorta do the same thing.
- Do use InnoDB; that link you quote was resoundingly refuted -- the author admitted it.
- Do not use `LEFT JOIN` if `JOIN` gives you what you want.  `LEFT` implies that the 'right' table may have missing rows.
- `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` usually cannot be optimized, but `JOIN` *might* be.
- This is especially inefficient:  `( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )`
- "explode-implode":  `JOINing` inflates the number of rows; `GROUP BY` then deflates.  This is a common cause of performance issues.  (Maybe I can be more specific as I go along.)
- `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for not being `NULL`.  *Usually*, what you really want is `COUNT(*)`.

For clarity in reading, and for "correctness" when using `LEFT JOIN`, put only 'connecting' conditions in the `ON`; put 'filtering' conditions in `WHERE`.  I *think* `AND  pcc.qty=1` should be moved from `ON` to `WHERE`.  (And I think it *may* change the resultset.)

Possible indexes:

```
p: INDEX(deleted, name, id)
l: INDEX(practice_fk)
```

Do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  If you don't see "auto-key", then you have an old version of MySQL; consider upgrading.  "auto-key" says that my comment about `( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` does not apply.  Otherwise, consider two `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and add an index on `..._fk`.  Then use the tmp tables instead of `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` twice.

Do what you can with my comments, then come back with revised query, plus `EXPLAIN` for further critique (if necessary).

More on creating indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Thank you so very much, Rick! This response is one of the best SO responses I've received -- the explanation is deeply appreciated.

LEFT Join is being used as a practice can exist without locations or contacts, and a JOIN would remove them from the response, ime.

I'll revise the subqueries more. I'm still fairly green with SQL, this being one of my more complex tasks yet.

I removed DISTINCT, as GROUP BY helps remove duplicate results.

Tom Shir's response with the indexes helped speed things up exponentially as well. Your two answers helped resolve this issue, so thank you!!

Comment: @TomJ - Glad you understand `LEFT`.  Your explanation is nice and concise.  (All joins being `LEFT` often means "green with SQL".)

Comment: yeah, I used to be quite guilty of `LEFT JOIN`ing everything; have come a long way since then haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't really need to order by anything in the subqueries. Therefore, you can explicitly set ORDER BY NULL to improve performance of the subqueries.

Modified query:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT p.id AS practice_id,
        p.name,
        l.id AS location_id,
        l.address AS location_address,
        l.phone AS disp_phone,
        CONCAT(pc.fname,
        ' ',
        pc.lname) AS practiceContact,
        CONCAT(lc.fname,
        ' ',
        lc.lname) AS locationContact,
        pcc.qty AS practice_only_contact_qty,
        lcc.qty AS location_contact_qty,
        (pcc.qty + lcc.qty) AS contactQty 
    FROM
        practices p 
    LEFT JOIN
        practice_locations l 
            ON l.practice_fk = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(practice_contacts.id) AS qty,
                practice_contacts.practice_fk 
            FROM
                practice_contacts 
            GROUP BY
                practice_contacts.practice_fk 
            ORDER BY
                NULL
        ) pcc 
            ON pcc.practice_fk = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        practice_contacts pc 
            ON pc.practice_fk = pcc.practice_fk 
            AND pcc.qty = 1 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(practice_contacts.id) AS qty,
                practice_contacts.location_fk 
            FROM
                practice_contacts 
            GROUP BY
                practice_contacts.location_fk 
            ORDER BY
                NULL
        ) lcc 
            ON lcc.location_fk = l.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        practice_contacts lc 
            ON lc.location_fk = lcc.location_fk 
            AND lcc.qty = 1 
    WHERE
        p.name IS NOT NULL 
        AND p.deleted IS NULL 
    GROUP BY
        p.id 
    ORDER BY
        p.name ASC,
        l.state,
        l.city,
        l.address
```

Also, add the following indexes which might optimize your query:

```
ALTER TABLE `practices` ADD INDEX `practices_index_1` (`deleted`,`id`,`name`);
ALTER TABLE `practice_contacts` ADD INDEX `practice_contacts_index_1` (`practice_fk`,`location_fk`);
ALTER TABLE `practice_contacts` ADD INDEX `practice_contacts_index_2` (`location_fk`);
ALTER TABLE `practice_locations` ADD INDEX `practice_locations_index_1` (`practice_fk`,`id`);
```

Comment: Tom, thank you so much for your elaborate, and informative response. The indexes you added here brought the query down from 21 seconds to 0.05 seconds -- much much better. Between you and Rick James, you two resolved this issue, so thank you!

Comment: @TomJ, thanks for the feedback, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting the number of contacts and practices, you could use the ROW LIMIT syntax to always return the first row. I cannot guarantee that it will help with performance but it's two less joins to worry about.

```
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * 
            FROM practice_contacts 
            GROUP BY practice_fk LIMIT 1
        ) pcc ON pcc.practice_fk=p.id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT *
            FROM practice_locations
            GROUP BY practicec_fk LIMIT 1
        ) lcc ON lcc.practice_fk = p.id
```

I didn't verify that the sql will work but you get the idea. If you need a specific contact or location (for example, the most recent) you can include an ORDER BY clause in the subselects.

See [Does MySQL "SELECT LIMIT 1" with multiple records select first record from the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517246/does-mysql-select-limit-1-with-multiple-records-select-first-record-from-the-t)

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, you cannot reliably predict which record will be returned.  With an `ORDER BY`, performance _may_ suffer.